# Multiple databases: store users in remote database

Tags: users, database, multi-sites

I want to have one site with two different databases: one should store users and other should store the rest. Databases are on independent servers.
I know that in settings.php there can be several databse connections. But how can I tell the User module not to use default one?

Comment: What is your reasoning for having two seperate databases like this? AFAIK splitting up a single Drupal site in this manner is not recommended. If you explain in a little more detail what your functional requirements are I could try recommend a better solution.

Comment: Basically, you can't simply "tell module to use different DB". More details can be found [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11274342/2389310).

Comment: Actually I want multiple sites to share users. But the solution when multiple sites share one database is not for this case. Each site should have it's own db and one common with users.

Comment: Have you checked to see if MySQL _itself_ can support single-query joining across tables in databases located on different servers? I imagine it does in some way, however bad for performance - but If it can't, this is all moot anyway